# UIKeyboardWillHideNotification delay in animation

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I have registered the two UIKeyboardNotifications (keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide) and both are being triggered. The issue comes in when the animation for textfield to move back to the original position only gets fired  after the keyboard disappears. Is there anyway to reduce the lag between getting the notification and animating the textfield?

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame : CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    duration = (info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.doubleValue)
    let rawAnimationCurve = (notification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber).unsignedIntValue << 16
    animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(rawAnimationCurve))
    let moveAmount = keyboardFrame.height
    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration!, delay:0, options: animationCurve, animations: {
        self.txtfield.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, -self.moveAmount)
        }, completion:nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay:0, options:animationCurve, animations: {
            self. txtfield.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0)
            }, completion:nil)
}
```

[GIF image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PE68.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realised a problem, it was a careless mistake by me.

Added :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(viewController.keyboardDidHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

instead of :

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(viewController.keyboardWillHide), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```